# How to specify the log tag from docker compose on google logging?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fluentd

In my docker compose file, I can specify the logging driver as a "fluentd" and by default, it pushes the log to the listener of `google-fluentd` on port `24224`

I can see the log appear on the logging page along with the tag as the container Id.

[image]

Howerver, look like I cannot figure out how to change the tag name to something I want (instead of container Id)

My configuration in the docker compose is quite simple

```
logging:
  driver: fluentd
  options:
    tag: "my-server" # does not work
```

Update: look like the options are not effective. No matter what I change in the tag option, it does not work. Even when I put some crazy options, it still run but without the correct tag

Answer (score 1):

Problem solve: I need to remove the container and create it again. the new tag will get affected